# Как получить список ссылок на ролики канала YouTube?

Tags: php, youtube

Есть код, который выводит список названий видео на YouTube-канале:

```
<?php     
$content=file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/user/Fletcher2008/videos');

$content=preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/"/','',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/href=\/watch\?v=/',"\n",$content);
$content=preg_replace('/<(span|img)[^>]*>/','',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/<\/(span|img)>/','',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/[\s]*class=[^>^\n]*>/','>',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/>[\s]*/','>',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/[\s]*</','<',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/<button.*/','',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/><\/a>/','\',\'',$content);
$content=preg_replace('/<\/a>.*/','',$content);
$lines = preg_split('/\n/', $content);

$count=0;
foreach($lines as $line){
    if($count==0) { 
        $count=1;
    } else if($count==1) {
        $sql.="('".$line."',";
        $count=2;
    } else if($count==2) {
        $line=preg_replace('/^[^>]*>/','',$line);
        $sql.="'".$line."'),\n";
        $count=1;
        echo $line."<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Подскажите, как вывести ещё и ссылки на эти видео?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя ваш подход можно сделать так:

```
<?php

$content=file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/user/Fletcher2008/videos');

if (preg_match_all('%<h3 class="yt-lockup-title"><a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)%iu', $content, $matches))
{
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $count = count($matches[0]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        echo htmlspecialchars($matches[1][$i], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        echo ' --- ';
        echo htmlspecialchars($matches[2][$i], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        echo "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

P.S. Но у ютуба есть api для этого.

Comment: Спасибо, а если несколько ссылок, например:
$content=file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/user/Fletcher2008/videos');
$content=file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/user/gsstudiodota/videos');

как сделать что бы они поочереди парсились

Comment: Ссылки страниц ютуба поместите в массив и перебирайте их в цикле, а внутри цикла парсите текущую.

Comment: а можете пример набросать?

Comment: Если вы не знаете как написать цикл и вставить данный код внутрь цикла, то вам следует обратиться на биржу фриланса с этой задачей.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я разобрался !